# Open pdf in adobe reader from https

Tags: android, pdf, adobe-reader

This gives me the toast message error: `Document could not be opened`:

```
Intent adobeIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
if (adobeIntent != null) {
    adobeIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf"), "application/pdf");
    startActivity(adobeIntent);
}
```

And this is working fine:

```
Intent adobeIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
if (adobeIntent != null) {
    adobeIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf"), "application/pdf");
    startActivity(adobeIntent);
}
```

Am I missing a parameter or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Don't use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` when you want to view a PDF. For example, the launcher activity for Adobe Reader is not the PDF-viewing activity. Use `ACTION_VIEW`, please.

Comment: difference between http and https

Comment: If I use `ACTION_VIEW` it won't give me the option to open in adobe reader on https - I wan't the file to open in Adobe Reader or another compatible pdf reader